# Retrieving records from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

So like the title suggests, I am trying to retrieve records from multiple tables.
I have the following tables : `ads1` , `ads2` , `ads3` ,.... each tables containes 1 or more records with auto_increment `id` and names of people under the column named `names`.

Let's say I have 10 records in each tables, and I have a pagination script that shows 5 records per page, that means 2 pages for each table, so I will have pages `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`.
My algorithm doesn't do it correctly, on my first page it shows 5 record from the first table, 5 records from the second table , 5 records from the third table and so on... but I only want 5 records to be shown per page , not 5 from each table that I have, I want them to be shown correctly on pages `1` and `2` records from `ads1` , on pages `3` and `4` records from `ads2` and so on, hope you get the idea.
Can you please help me ?

here is my alogorithm :

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$kay;$i++)
{
    $counter = 0;
    $tablenow = 'ads'.$i;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ".$tablenow." ");

    $counter = $counter + mysql_num_rows($result);
    $x=ceil($counter / $per_page);
    $page = (isset ($_GET['page']) AND (int)$_GET['page'] > 0 AND (int)$_GET['page'] <= $x) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
    $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$tablenow." ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 
    $start,$per_page ")or die(mysql_error());
    while ($sqlg=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        // this is where I show the records.
    }
}
```

PS: For only one table , the algorithm works exactly as it should, but when I have 2 or more tables it stops working correctly.

Comment: Posted a suggested rewrite but I see you've got it working already.  Just one suggestion: the original mysql API you are using is deprecated.  It is recommended that you use the "MySQL Improved Extension": http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php.  You could also use PDO if you feel you might change databases in the future: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$count_tables = 10;
$query        = '';
for ($table_no = 1; $table_no <= $count_tables; $table_no++ ) {
  $query .= "SELECT * FROM ads" . $table_no . " UNION ";
}
// Remove trailing UNION
$query = preg_replace( '/ UNION \Z/', '', $query );

$result     = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ".$tablenow." ");
$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$max_page   = ceil( $total_rows / $per_page );

// Fetch rows for the page
$query_for_page .= $query . " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page";
$page = ( isset ($_GET['page'])
          AND (int)$_GET['page'] > 0
          AND (int)$_GET['page'] <= $max_page ) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

$page_results = mysql_query( $query_for_page ) or die( mysql_error() );
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $page_results ) ) {
  // this is where I show the records.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute only one query, which will be an `UNION` of the results of all desired tables. If you execute `SELECT`s in each table individually, you cannot track the total results in an accurate way.

Comment: I see, but how do I execute and UNION of multiple tables, please keep in mind that tables are dynamically created, so I don't know how many table I have created in my db only by running a function that retrieves the number of the tables.